# jQuery selector for the child of a parent's previous sibling

Tags: jquery

For each stat block like the following:

```
<div class="stats">
  <div class="label">
    <span class="goal">10 YEARS OF SOMETHING GOOD</span>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <div class="tri"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the marginRight of `tri` to half the width of the previous `goal`.  Which jQuery selector would I use to grab the previous 'goal' relative to each `tri` ?

Something like..

```
$(function(){
  $('.tri').css({marginRight: function() {
    return Math.floor($(this).something('.goal').width() / 2) + 'px';
  }})
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find('.goal').width()
```

This also works:

```
$(this).parents('.stats').find('.label > .goal').width()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I wasn't sure if I could do a parent().prev().find() or if it would be a chain of the 3.

Comment: The latter doesn't work if there are multiple (label,stat) pairs within .stats.

Comment: @arby: Of course, chaining is what makes the whole thing easy ;)

Comment: @Aleski: Yes, I thought about that, but just thought it would be nice to know an alternative solution